# Error building hadoop 1.0.1 - missing pom.xml

Tags: maven, ubuntu, hadoop

I followed the instructions given [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute) to download and build hadoop 1.0.1 from this [repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-X.Y.Z). I have installed JDK, Maven, cmake, autoconf etc. When I run  th efollowing command from the hadoop top level directory

```
   mvn -e package -Pdist -Pdoc -Psrc -Dtar -DskipTests
```

mvn reports an error saying that no pom.xml is found. There is no pom.xml file in the folder or any subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I investigate the [Hadoop Common tags](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/), only version `0.23.x` and `2.0.x` is a `Maven` project. The rest is an `Ant` and/or `Ivy` project. Please note If there is no `pom.xml` it is not a `Maven` project.

If you would like to build the version `1.0.1`, please use [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) instead.

Comment: Thanks! I wondered what I was doing wrong. Are there instructions for building Hadoop using Ant?